# I can not display Image network in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

My error:

```
*══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ImageCodecException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Failed to detect image file format using the file header.
File header was [0x3c 0x21 0x44 0x4f 0x43 0x54 0x59 0x50 0x45 0x20].
Image source: http://localhost:49909/
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49  throw_
lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/image_web_codecs.dart 52:7                       create
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54            runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5            _async
lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/image_web_codecs.dart 35:46                      create
lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/image.dart 88:34                                 skiaInstantiateWebImageCodec
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1653:54                                          runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18 *
```

Comment: Provide your source code where you're trying to display image. And your asset section in pubspec.yaml

Comment: Instead of "networkimage" it must be your img file path

Comment: Where are your images in your project?

Comment: yes is  imag path

Comment: if I build html it work  it error when i build canvaskit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build web using **--web-renderer html** tag, run following command from project root in terminal:

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```

To display images on flutter web, using **--web-renderer canvaskit** won't work!